# Can an opensource project get its own stackoverflow site at projectName.stackoverflow.com?

Tags: discussion, support

I've seen all the answers suggesting to use other stackoverflow engines or telling it's only for internal use in big organizations like Apple or MS. But seeing facebook.stackoverflow.com & askubuntu.com made me ask this question. Can a big open source project with a huge user base & a developer community get its own stackoverflow site? Maybe not even on its own domain but on a subdomain like projectABC.stackoverflow.com.

Comment: Is it even big enough to support more than just being tagged with the project name among the other programming questions?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you want to try and get your own site, you can go through the [Area 51](http://area51.stackexchange.com/) process. You propose a site, gain more attention, and eventually, if you have enough of a following, you will reach a Beta site.

Facebook.stackoverflow is just for a specific tag. If this isn't programming related, you can try Area 51.