# Providing subdomains of SO to popular open source projects

Tags: feature-request, stack-overflow, subdomains

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can an opensource project get its own stackoverflow site at projectName.stackoverflow.com?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/122031/can-an-opensource-project-get-its-own-stackoverflow-site-at-projectname-stackove)

I'm wondering if it is possible (or will be in the future) to have a subdomain on Stack Overflow like ffmpeg.stackoverflow.com, which features only issues related to the ffmpeg project (www.ffmpeg.org).

This way it would not be necessary for people to ask for open source code and stuff, but could instead apply for the subdomain on your server. Also, this would really help open source projects, that always lack funds for development, to switch their support to (at least) one level up in quality.

I don't know if this is a reasonable request at all and it doesn't mean it should be completely free and available to everyone who requests it, but it's a thought to improve projects, that always lack time and funds for such things.

Comment: Pretty sure Facebook only has that because they reached a special deal.

Comment: Closely related: [Introduce sub-communities (or “Portals”) to prevent fragmentation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/94591)

Answer (score 10):

It was tried with facebook.stackoverflow.com, didn't work as expected and the idea seems pretty much dead now.

You can still view only ffmpeg-related posts by looking at the [ffmpeg](/questions/tagged/ffmpeg) tag, you don't need a subdomain for that. If an open source project wants to use SO to help their developers, they only need to start reading the questions there about their project and start answering them.

One problem is also that SE isn't a good fit for many types of interactions such projects need (bug reports, discussions), so an SE site can only ever be a supplement to other resources. Stackexchange is not a bug tracker nor a forum, it's not really meant for all kinds of support but for questions and answers.